# Android Galaxy OutputStreamWriter causing a excetion, but runs on all my other android devices

Tags: android

I have code to log a person in with a user name password from a web server.  The code works fine on my other android devices (Vergin mobile, acer tablet) which are android 2.2 and 3.1.
But it crashes on the new Galaxy phones.

when the code executes
 OutputStreamWriter wr3 = new OutputStreamWriter(conn3.getOutputStream());

The code causes a exception Networkonmainthread exception and the reason is null.
I was wondering is their a security issue  using android 4,1???? Since it works on my other devices which are 3.1 and 2.2?

code

```
try {
    // Construct data
    Editable ed = mPassWord.getText();
    cGlobals.PassWord=ed.toString();

    ed = mUserName.getText();
    cGlobals.UserName=ed.toString();

    String data = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode( cGlobals.UserName, "UTF-8");
    data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(  cGlobals.PassWord, "UTF-8");


    // Send data
    URL url = new URL("http://www.tellafortune.com/mobile/login.php");
    // URL url = new URL("http://www.hhhhtellafortune.com/mobile/login.php");

    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

    wr.write(data);
    wr.flush();

    // Get the response

    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        out += line;
    }

    wr.close();
    rd.close();

    if (!out.contains("ok"))
        return false;    

    // Send data
    URL url2 = new URL("http://www.tellafortune.com/mobile/getaddr.php");
    // URL url = new URL("http://www.hhhhtellafortune.com/mobile/login.php");

    URLConnection conn2 = url2.openConnection();
    conn2.setDoOutput(true);
    OutputStreamWriter wr2 = new OutputStreamWriter(conn2.getOutputStream());

    wr2.write(data);
    wr2.flush();

    // Get the response

    BufferedReader rd2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn2.getInputStream()));
    String line2;
    out="";
    while ((line2 = rd2.readLine()) != null) {
        out+=line2;
    }

    wr2.close();
    rd2.close();

    cGlobals.strServerAddre=out.replaceAll("\n","");



    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //////// Get port number if it is the scocial game
    if (ChatOrGame != 1) {
        // String port=new String(":4999/add");
        String port=new String(":4998/add");
        URL url3 = new URL( cGlobals.strServerAddre + port);

        URLConnection conn3 = url3.openConnection();
        conn3.setDoOutput(true);
        // crashes on this line
        OutputStreamWriter wr3 = new OutputStreamWriter(conn3.getOutputStream());

        wr3.write(data);
        wr3.flush();

        // Get the response

        BufferedReader rd3 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn3.getInputStream()));
        String line3;
        out="";
        while ((line3 = rd3.readLine()) != null) {
            out+=line3;
        }

        wr3.close();
        rd3.close();

        cGlobals.strPortNumber=out.replaceAll("PORT:","");
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Internet Error")
        .setMessage( "Cannot talk to server" )
        .setNeutralButton("close",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener();
}
```

Comment: You cant run most network operations on the main thread to cut down on UI lag.  wrap this code in an asynctask to do the work in the background,  here is a overview & tutorial : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The code causes a exception Networkonmainthread exception and the reason is null.

You are performing network I/O on the main thread. While allowed before Android 4.0, it was never a good idea. Please move your network I/O to a background thread, such as one supplied by an `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Thank you, I was really stumped